# Bouncy Castle Example Source Needed

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, bouncycastle

Hi I'm looking for some source-code or good documentation on Bouncy Castle's SSL/TLS functions.  I need this also to the client side for Java.  I have looked everywhere and read books on the subject and didn't found anything.

Comment: Did you look at the example (test) programs included with the distribution? How far have you gotten in your coding? I haven't used it in twelve years, but I don't recall having any particular difficulty getting it to work (SSL-capable proxy with on-the-fly certificate creation).

Comment: I thought there may be some test programs but I can;t find them :( can you send me a link? Thanks for the reply BTW!

Comment: They are mentioned on the [documentation page](http://www.bouncycastle.org/documentation.html). They weren't in the package?

Comment: The test programs are inside of the source tar.gz file for whichever JDK you are using. Extract the tar.gz, inside the extracted folder is a file called src.zip, unzip it and the test programs are in there.